# Getting rows that are having distinct id with bulk collect - Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the records that are having distinct member id using bulk collect.
My query is like below:

```
  ...
    type members_nt is table of table2%rowtype;
    members_bc      members_nt;
  ...
select t2.* bulk collect
        into members_bc
        from table1 t1
            ,table2 t2
       where t1.isn= t2.isn
         and t1.customer= customer
         and t1.insert_date between ... and ... );
```

t2 table has a column named member_id and what I want to get into *members_bc* is the rows having distinct member_id.

**For example if my t2 table has something like this:**

```
  name  |  surname  | account   | member_id 
  john       alby      abc         123   
  john       alby      def         123 
  mary       hale      lkj         234
```

**I want to bulk collect only**

```
name  |  surname  | account   | member_id
john       alby      abc          123
mary       hale      lkj          234
```

or

```
name  |  surname  | account   | member_id
john       alby      def          123
mary       hale      lkj          234
```

It does not matter which one. But memberid must be unique in the *members_bc*.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to give each row a number per `member_id` and then filter to only get the first row.

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE members_nt IS TABLE OF table2%ROWTYPE;
  members_bc members_nt;
BEGIN
  SELECT t2.name, t2.surname, t2.account, t2.member_id
  BULK COLLECT INTO members_bc
  FROM  (
    SELECT t2.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY member_id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
    FROM   table2 t2
  ) t2
  WHERE  rn = 1;

  FOR i IN 1 .. members_bc.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( members_bc(i).member_id || ' ' || members_bc(i).name );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> 123 john
> 234 mary
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=932c2e27251831c6a6c56eede558ef83)*

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid "select *" and just enter the desired columns by creating a cursor for your select and then creating a %rowtype of the cursor. 
Using @MT0 answer as baseline template.)

```
declare
  cursor members_cur is 
         select t2.name, t2.surname, t2.account, t2.member_id
           from ( select t2.name, t2.surname, t2.account, t2.member_id
                       , row_number() over ( partition by member_id order by rownum ) as rn
                   from table2 t2
                ) t2
          where rn = 1;

  type members_tt is table of members_cur%rowtype;
  members_bc members_tt;
begin
  open  members_cur; 
  fetch members_cur 
   bulk collect into members_bc;
  close members_cur; 

  for i in 1 .. members_bc.count 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(members_bc(i).member_id || ' ' ||members_bc(i).name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use aggregation, e.g.

```
select name,  
       surname, 
       min(account) as account,        --> this
       member_id
from ...
group by name, surname, member_id      --> and this
```

Comment: How does bulk collect into fit in this answer? In my table, I have lots of columns so I don't want to write all of them one by one after the select statement. My problem was that I could not find a solution that works with bulk collect into statement.

Comment: Using `select *` is most probably wrong in production systems. For quick/testing/development purposes - OK, we all do it. But for *real stuff*, no thanks. By the way, if you started typing, you'd already be over with those *lots of columns*. And no - I'm not joking and I'm not making fun of you - just trying to tell you what is the right thing to do.

Comment: `SELECT *` is not wrong when you are using `%ROWTYPE` data types as you want all the columns in exactly the correct order and if the table structure changes (not that it should) then you will still want all the columns in exactly the correct order and you just need to recompile the procedure/package to get the PL/SQL working.